# GDB structure output

Tags: c, gdb

I haven't worked with gdb for a long time and this feels like a basic question.

I am trying to observe a structure as it changes but rather than break at a specific point and print it out I'd rather let the application run as normal and give me a snapshot of the structure at a specific point.  Think a breakpoint that performs an action (print struct) rather than pausing execution.

I am interested in looking at the changes to the structure all at once rather than incrementally.  I can get what I want through printf, but gdb is much more elegant.

**Update:**  Thank you for all the responses.  I want to watch one struct at a particular point and the commands solution is just what I needed.  This has been very helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A nice approach is to set a breakpoint with associated commands, e.g:

```
break main.c:100
commands 1
print data_structure
continue
end
```

This runs the two commands `print data_structure` and `continue` whenever breakpoint 1 is reached.

Comment: Or even better - set a watchpoint, so you can catch ALL places where the structure is being modified.

Comment: Right - but the original question used the words "specific point" twice. Often, a structure will be frequently touched by many pieces of code, but only one particular one is of interest.

Answer (score 2):

If the information held by your data structure might be changed by several code lines, you can also use gdb's `watch`. Note that it is horribly slow so it should be used carefully. The commands part is just the same.

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483b5:
(gdb) run
Breakpoint 1, main ()
(gdb) watch data_structure
Hardware watchpoint 2: data_structure
(gdb) commands 2
Type commands for when breakpoint 2 is hit, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
> print data_structure
> continue
> end
(gdb) continue
```